# With and Without Dot Notation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to write the following without using dot notation ...

```
[scrollView setMinimumZoomScale: scrollView.bounds.size.width / image.size.width];
```

Is this right?

```
[scrollView setMinimumZoomScale: [scrollView bounds].size.width / [image size].width];
```

cheers Gary.

Comment: Yes, you can... But what exactly the question is?

Comment: What's wrong with dot notation?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, I just prefer to use bracket notation where possible.

Comment: What is wrong with dot notation is that it overloads another piece of similar C syntax which can get confusing, for example, what does this do: `scrollView.bounds.size.width = 5.0`.  If NSRect and its size member were Objective-C objects, it would probably do what you expect i.e. `[[[scrollView bounds] size] setWidth: 5.0]`, but it's not, it's actually `[scrollView bounds].size.width = 5.0`  Hopefuly the compiler would warn you that you are discarding the assignment result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually is something *wrong* with dot notation. It can get really ugly and hard to read in objective-c. While you'll get differing opinions and flame wars (which I probably just started), I'll be glad to share with you my rule of thumb. Use dot notation for structs. Use brackets for everything else. Read Joe Conway's (of Big Nerd Ranch) [blog post on the subject](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=83).

Money quote from Joe:

> It is my belief, after teaching
>   roughly 300 students Objective-C, that
>   dot-notation is confusing. It hinders
>   the main goal of software development:
>   writing maintainable, effective,
>   efficient, easy to read and bug-free
>   code.

In answer to your question, YES! Looks perfect. You're accessing a *struct* with your dots.

Stick to your guns on the dot notation. Don't let anyone bully you into using them. ;-)

-Matt

Comment: "It is my belief, after reading roughly 300 StackOverflow posts on Objective-C, that dot-notation is confusing."

Comment: Thank you Matt, I became aware of the controversy surrounding dot notation when I stared learning objective-c (about 6 months ago), so to simplify my learning I decided to stick with the original bracket notation. Now I prefer it and always use it, I will read Joes blog as a point of reference, much appreciated.

Comment: in this situation its easy to see whats object and whats struct [scrollView bounds].size.width if you went with dot notation you could easily be led to believe you were accessing all objects.

Comment: Sorry, but the BNR guys are wrong on this account. Dot notation gives the developer a clear difference between property access and sending a message. Granted sometimes they can be the same, but there are often objects who have properties with no methods. Further abstracting how the object sets its value is a good thing.

Comment: @jshier using dot notation and sending a message are *always* the same. If an object has properties you can access those properties using standard bracket methods. This is exactly the sort of confusion that dot.notation leads to.

Comment: Not that I'm anti-dot.notation. I use it 100% of the time to access properties. I'm just agreeing with @matt and Joe Conway and everyone else that asserts that dot.notation leads to needless confusion.

Comment: @jshier this is *exactly* why dot notation is wrong.  It's led you to believe that there is a difference between property access and sending a message.  There isn't.

Comment: @kubi, @JeremyP: I was mostly trying to restate what I read here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/in-defense-of-objective-c-20-properties.html

Comment: @JeremyP He was referring to the intent displayed in the source code. In fact, dot-notation can be more informative than brackets because it designates between behavioral methods and property getters.